# discord.py few tasks working some not [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send']

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

hey its me again after succesfully got my first 3 tasks running perfectly the next one is doing me some headache.. its nearly the same code as in other tasks from me.

Code:

```
    @tasks.loop(seconds=20)
async def online_stats():
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(target_channel_id2)
    link = my_link
    f = requests.get(link)
    sys.stdout = open("test2.txt", "w")
    print(f.text)
    sys.stdout.close()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename2, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
         print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text), end="")
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename2, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
         print(line.replace(text_to_search2, replacement_text2), end='') 
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename2, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
         print(line.replace(text_to_search3, replacement_text2), end='')
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename2, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
         print(line.replace(text_to_search4, replacement_text2), end='')
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename2, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
         print(line.replace(text_to_search5, replacement_text3), end='')
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename2, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
         print(line.replace(text_to_search6, replacement_text4), end='')
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename2, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
         print(line.replace(text_to_search7, replacement_text5), end='')
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename2, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
         print(line.replace(text_to_search8, replacement_text6), end='')

    with open('test2.txt') as fp:
        lines=fp.readlines()
    await message_channel.send(lines[148].strip('\n') + " " + lines[150])
    await message_channel.send(lines[156].strip('\n') + " " + lines[158].strip('\n'))
    await message_channel.send(lines[164].strip('\n') + " " + lines[166].strip('\n'))
    await message_channel.send(lines[172].strip('\n') + " " + lines[174].strip('\n'))
    await message_channel.send(lines[180].strip('\n') + " " + lines[182].strip('\n'))
```

console output

```
    Unhandled exception in internal background task 'online_stats'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\0x9\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\discord_bot_pi_aktuell.py", line 411, in online_stats
    await message_channel.send(lines[148].strip('\n') + " " + lines[150])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

its basically the same code i'm using for a command which is working, but if i wanna use the code for a task its not working cause of "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send"

ty for every answer! may u all have great eastern.

Edit: For all who are running in the same issue this is the solution to solve it:

you have the make a before loop

```
@online_stats.before_loop
async def before():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print("Finished waiting")
```

Comment: the target channel id is not valid, hence `message_channel` is None and you can't send

Comment: weird cause if i add the ID 827255114196713482 instead as the variable the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is caused by an API error, your bot can't get the channel I'd that you pitted in at

```
message_channel = bot.get_channel(id)
```

You should check if the bot can currently see that channel. If he is not in the server that contains that channel, you can't neither send a message or get that channel.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, i changed it to message_channel = bot.get_channel(827255114196713482) but getting the same attributeerror. the bot can see the channel, the other task is working fine with the same channel

Comment: Ok, then try to use `bot.fetch_channel`. Idk why you are getting that error, it seems like that your bot cannot get that channel.

Comment: found the problem, it wasn the bot.get_channel function i just forgot the before.loop function..ty anyways for your help! i edited the main post with the solution

Comment: Perfect, i hope i helped you!